# Replace Win7 w/ Win8 after setup w/ Ubuntu 13.10 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

My machine now runs dual boot with Win 7 and ubuntu 13.10. I have installed the Win 7 first on my pc in C Drive then I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 in D drive. I used GRUB 2.0 for Dual boot.

When I boot my pc I have to select the OS I want to login. There are ubuntu and win 7 listed. Which I think a screen appeared from ubuntu OS. Now I want to install a fresh copy of win 8 in C Drive. Is there any precaution or steps of work should I follow for this installation? Or I install both OS again?

Answer (score 1):

Install windows 8 in your C drive. Download   [Ubuntu boot repair disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/).Make a liveCd or live USB(you can do this from windows using softwares like unetbootin, or you can make a liveUSB from Ubuntu before installing windows.)

Restart and boot into liveUSB or live CD, and do a recommended repair to recover your grub and Ubuntu.

Usually everything should be ok by this procedure

Comment: Can you please rephrase the steps please.